# Cannot retry MapEngine.initi() after "Not allowed to start service Intent ... app is in background" error

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

I've got a problem in SDK init behavior - after

```
Not allowed to start service Intent ... app is in background
```

error happens (which is described here - [HERE SDK is unusable in background on Android 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48378267/5442357))

`MapEngine.isInitialized()` returns false (which is correct)
But next call to `MapEngine.getInstance().init()` throws error - `Engine cannot be initialized twice`

We want to allow user retry initialization after failed attempt. Is there another way of doing that? Is there way to create clean map engine without restarting an application?

Comment: have you tried foreground service
also try initializing mapEngine when application starts
I personally initalize it from application file not activity and call isInitialized in Activities

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make sure mapEngine initialized while the application is not in background.
To avoid this behavior you'll need to use foreground service.
Please below github sample.
https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/tree/master/turn-by-turn-navigation/